# Make dictionary from a chart setup

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, dictionary

I'm trying to use keys (sizes of pipe) that have outlets of different sizes. Each outlet has its own set of sizes. I created dictionaries within a dictionary style which is called from a pickerView. But I can't call individual items from the buried dictionaries/arrays...

```
               -------> _____
                 |     |     |
                 M  ___|     |___      size >>>     1/2"
                 |_|__ _ __      |                ___|___
                   |______|______|                |     |
                   |      |      |  outlets >>>  1/2"  3/8"
                   |__C___|___C__|               /\     /\
                                                /  \   /  \
                                               C    M C    M
```

I have already tried this setup with a structure and also tried individual dictionaries that all call to each other:>>

`var out2 = ["1": [["1": [1.5 , 1.5]], ["3/4": [1.5 , 1.5]], ["1/2": [1.5 , 1.5]]]]`

This does work but I can't call individual pieces from it.

```
struct teeDict {
var out1: [(size: String) : 
        [[(outlet1: String) : 
    [(c: Double) ,  (m: Double)]], 
        [(outlet2: String) : 
    [(c: Double) , (m: Double)]]]] = 
            ["1/2" : 
           [["1/2" : 
          [1.0 , 1.0]], 
             ["3/8" : 
          [1.0 , 1.0]]]]
}
```

I tried to create a dictionary instead of using arrays but nothing is recognized. How do I get this to work?? Thanks.

[SOURCE DATA](http://fir-9898-work.blogspot.com/2017/01/pipe-fitters-blue-book.html?view=snapshot) (for clarification)

Comment: You images and words seem at odds.  Are you saying that. (a) a size of pipe can have several different outlets, and that each of these outlets can also have several different sizes or (b) a size of pipe can have several different outlets of varying sizes?  i.e. is a 3-tier data structure or just 2-tier.

Comment: you should really consider creating your own struct or class to make this infinitely more readable as well but yes flanker has the right question here

Comment: This is a 3-tier structure.  Basically, each "size" (A) contains up to 8 "outlet sizes" (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I) and each outlet size contains only 2 values (as above -> "C" and "M".

Comment: flanker: option A, please

Comment: Also, I just updated the post with a link to the source info chart. Its page 97.